# I get NAN when trying to get my current location - longitude and latitude

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, latitude-longitude

I wrote a very simple application which just get the current location of the phone - longitude and latitude and prints them. The problem is I get `NAN` for both longitude and latitude. Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
  GeoPosition<GeoCoordinate> GC = new GeoPosition<GeoCoordinate>();
  GC = watcher.Position;
  double latitude = GC.Location.Latitude;
  double longitude = GC.Location.Longitude;
  textBlock1.Text = "longitude: " + longitude;
  textBlock2.Text = "latitude: " + latitude;
}
```

Comment: It's "longitude", not "longtitude" btw...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't remember the specifics.. But your GPS isn't just always on and thus doesn't know your location ALL the time.

You need to enable the GPS, and wait for it to get a lock (as said, I don't remember exactly how to do it). Only then it has coordinates.

Comment: Great! But not what I meant :-)
When you turn it on and create a GeoCoordinateWatcher it won't have coordinates just like that.

You will have to use the events, something like PositionChanged if I remember correctly.. That will get fired when the coordinates change, or get filled.

Comment: Plus even then it may not have a connection - GPS works nice outside, not so nice in buildings. Not in tunnels. Stuff like that.

Comment: Exactly. It can not be guaranteed that a location is known at any time. Therefore the NaNs are returned.

Comment: Yes that's was my problem - I added an event handler and now it's work, thank's!

Answer (score 2):

1) GPS has to be enabled at the phone
2) You have to start the watcher:

```
watcher.PositionChanged += YourPositionChangedHandler;
watcher.Start();
```

You can set an offset when the watcher should fire the event.
As I can remeber there is also a function like "TryGetPosition" where you don't have to start the watcher and just get the position once.